# Python EOF Error in the code

Tags: python, eof

```
numArr = [x for x in input().split()]

for num in numArr:

    if num == '+' or num >= 'a' and num <= 'z':

      print("invalid")

    elif int(num) >= 0 and int(num) <= 1000:     

      num_1 = str(num)

      count = 0

      for i in num_1:

        if i == '3':

        count += 1

    if int(num) % 3 == 0 and count > 0:

      print("dumb")

    elif count > 0:

      print("stupid")

    elif int(num) % 3 == 0:

      print("idiot")

    elif int(num) % 3 != 0 and count == 0:

      print("smart")

    else:

      print("invalid")
```

Is the above code fine? I got an EOF Error in a different editor i used. But this code executed in the Codechef IDE. What might be the problem?

Comment: Is it a script? Try to run it through command line like `python script.py` and see what happens

Comment: Please [edit] your code and remove all those blank lines. They make your code very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code, but your editor must be able to redirect input from the console to the python script; otherwise the python script would get EOF from the call to `input()`.